# TreeView Multiple Parents

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, treeview

I currently have a single treeview that is loading data from a single SQL database table. I've gotten it to load results, but I'm finding that it's loading the same parent node for each child object and only listing one child object beneath. How can I group these to have one parent to multiple children? The code I have is below. I tried using DISTINCT, but I'm not sure how I can, and couldn't get that to work when I have to pull multiple columns. I rally appreciate anyone's help!

For example, my table has:

```
WorkOrderName       ItemNumber
45123               101
45123               102
45123               103
```

And my treeview currently looks like:

```
+ 45123
  - 101
+ 45123
  - 102
+ 45123
  - 103
```

When I need it to look like this:

```
+ 45123
  - 101
  - 102
  - 103
```

Here is the code I have:

```
        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();

        try
        {
            cn.Open();
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Application.ExitThread();
        }

        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ProductTracking WHERE WorkOrderName IS NOT NULL ORDER BY WorkOrderName ASC", cn);

        try
        {
            SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode(dr["WorkOrderName"].ToString());
                node.Nodes.Add(dr["ItemNumber"].ToString());

                treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, you are creating a parent node for each database result. So... You should check if the parent already exists and a parent node if it does and don't if it doesn't.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to accomplish that in my code. I've not used treeviews prior to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just as a simple fix, you could dump the data in a `Dictionary` first:

*disclaimer:* this is just a quick fix; fully written and from the top of my head. i.e.: more efficient code can be written

```
try
{
    SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

    //create a dict of strings which holds a list of "items"
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        var orderName = (dr["WorkOrderName"].ToString();
        //fill the dictionary
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(orderName))
            dict.Add(orderName, new List<string>());

        dict[orderName].Add(dr["ItemNumber"].ToString());
    }

    //this should also be possible with a single linq statement
    //now loop the dictionary and fill the tree
    foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
    {
       //add parent
       TreeNode node = new TreeNode(key);

       //add childs
       foreach(var item in dict[key])
       {
           node.Nodes.Add(item);
       }

       //add it to the treeview
       treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the data in WorkOrderName order, you just need to track the parent node:

```
TreeNode parentNode = null;
while (dr.Read()) {
  string parentKey = dr["WorkOrderName"].ToString();
  if (parentNode == null || parentNode.Name != parentKey) {
    parentNode = treeView1.Nodes.Add(parentKey, parentKey);
  }
  parentNode.Nodes.Add(dr["ItemNumber"].ToString());
}
```